# How to use "in" keyword in c++

Tags: python, c++, string, stl

Hey I am a new C++ learner, I have been creating a program that do something specific...
I take input from the user, and converted it into a lowercased sentence,  then I use the "in"keyword like we use in python.... For example in python :

```
main_input = input("Type exit with a bunch of other words: ")
lower_input = main_input.lower()
if "exit" in lower_input:
    exit()
else:
    pass
```

What this does is that searches for the exit keyword from the input(like "ok you can **exit** now") and follows accordingly, exits the program.
But how to use "in" keyword in c++?
**I want to do something like this**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "boost/algorithm/string.hpp"
using namespace std;

int main() {

    while(true){
        std::string main_input;
        std::cout << "Type something: ";
        std::cin >> main_input;
        std::string lower_input = boost::algorithm::to_lower_copy(main_input);
/* the if statement below this, here is the problem...*/
        if("exit" in lower_input){
            std::cout << "Exiting";
            /* after that other statements if necessary to execute*/

        }

    }
  
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to do that?? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use [`find`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/), or if you want an exact match - just plain old `==`...

Comment: "_But how to use "in" keyword in c++?_" there is no `in` keyword in C++.

Comment: O.T.: I appreciate the fact that you prefixed every standard stuff with its scope `std::`. However, that makes the `using namespace std;` near top even more annoying... ;-)

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius got it!

Comment: @Scheff to be honest I am a python developer, and this is my 4th day learning c++!! I am a beginner, but I found what you told just now when i was messing around with `using namespace`, now I can write directly cout or cin instead of writing std::cout or std::cin!!

Comment: @ROG_SHAKHYAR If you are learning C++, consider learning from a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), since you can't learn it just by "messing around", due to various cases of [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior).

Comment: To be honest: Prefixing standard stuff with `std::` is completely fine and better than `using namespace std;` ([Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/7478597)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the member function `find` of the class `std::string`.

Something like

```
if ( lower_input.find( "exit" ) != std::string::npos ){
```

But it would be more accurate to write

```
if ( lower_input == "exit" ) {
```

because the user can enter a sentence that contains the symbols "exit" without an intention to break the loop.